# Possible to make a backup of original file in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

Is it is possible to make a copy of original file before writing the new buffer to the file without having to leave vim and copy it manually?

Answer (score 3):

You mean that you have already made some changes to the file in Vim you're about to `:write`, but want to backup the original file that's still on disk?

You can launch an external shell command directly from Vim. Vim's `:help cmdline-special` symbols avoid hard-coding the current filename, so you can easily turn this into a custom mapping or command:

```
:!cp % %.bak
```

Alternatively, you could use Vim's undo stack: First `:earlier 1f` command to temporarily restore the original file, `:write %.bak`, then `:later 1f`.

If you're looking for a complete backup solution, my [writebackupVersionControl plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1829) also has such command, as `:WriteBackupOfSavedOriginal`.

Comment: Exactly -- and that is a definitely solution on my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
set backup

function! BackupDir()
   if has('win32') || has('win64')
      let l:backupdir=$VIM.'/backup/'.
               \substitute(expand('%:p:h'), '\:', '~', '')
   else
      let l:backupdir=$HOME.'/.vim/backup/'.
               \substitute(expand('%:p:h'), '^'.$HOME, '~', '')
   endif

   if !isdirectory(l:backupdir)
      call mkdir(l:backupdir, 'p', 0700)
   endif

   let &backupdir=l:backupdir
   let &backupext=strftime('~%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S~')
endfunction

autocmd! bufwritepre * call BackupDir()
```

It causes Vim to save a uniquely-named backup file every single time I save any file. Backups are saved under `~/.vim/backup` (on Linux), in the directory hierarchy which replicates that of the original files. It's really easy to find a backup file when I need one. I've set this up once and forget; I need it very rarely (since usually all history is kept are in git), but when I do, it's just a life saver.

(by the way, just checked the size of my current `~/.vim/backup`, and it's 1.3 GB after ~2 years of working on this system; probably I'll need to do a cleanup soon)

Comment: I just want to write a command to take backup of the original file from vim, not having backup on all files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set `patchmode` ?

`:h patchmode`

if you set it to an contain a file extension vim will save a back-up of the original file.

Example:

`:set patchmode=.bak`

When you save a file e.g `orig.txt`, you will get two files: `orig.txt` - saved with new content. Old content in `orig.txt.bak`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).